# network.service Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking - Centos 7

Tags: centos, networkmanager, dhclient

I am experiencing an issue on Centos7 when attempting to start the network service. I receive the below error message.

```
Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking
```

The issue arised when I realised it wasn't taking my static IP address from the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file (found below).

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.16
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
HWADDR=B8:27:EB:C3:1E:EC
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

On reboot, the device would load with IP address of 192.168.0.7, clearly not that static IP address assigned, and not sure how it is getting information of a DHCP server (which I do have, my router)

I attempted to disable the NetworkManager, as this might have been causing havoc with the network service by issuing the below command.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

and then enable network

```
systemctl start network
```

again the same error came up, I then killed the dhclient process, and attempted to start network service once more and again got the same error.

Losing patience, since I did have connectivity to the internet at the time on the server through the DHCP IP, performed a "yum remove Network Manager" and tried a reboot, again to no avail. I'm not sure if that was a good idea or not, but hey it wasn't working anyway.

I seem to have exhausted suggestions I could find on the internet. Wondering if anybody else has any idea what might be going on.

edit: one more note, this is not a VM or related to Virtualisation in any way. This is simply a RaspberryPI 3

Many thanks.

Edit:
Log entries:

```
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking... 
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=6 
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking 
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state 
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: network.service failed
```

Comment: Just to make sure it is just a typo... when you say `/var/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` you actually do mean `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, right?

Comment: apologies, yes, my mistake, /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Comment: Have you made sure the `HWADDR` in that file really corresponds with the NIC?

Comment: I have checked the output of "ifconfig -a" and yes the ethernet address output from here matches that I have placed in the file.

Comment: Please post the system log from the boot time when the network interfaces are brought up, either from whichever file in `/var/log/` those things get logged to in CentOS or from the output of `journalctl -l -b 0`.

Comment: This is the info it shows me in the journal file
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=6
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state
Jan 01 00:00:06 <hostname> systemd[1]: network.service failed
Hope this helps. Let me know if there is further info that would seem helpful.

Comment: The log doesn't say much (btw, I copied it to the question body where it can be better formatted for readability). Please do also post the output of `systemctl -l status network.service`

Comment: Have you checked http://serverfault.com/q/660210/184397 and the accepted answer, looks similar?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the line in the `ifcfg-eth0`, which starts with `HWADDR` ?

Comment: Does dmesg show you anything of interest?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone is still having an issue with Centos 7 on the Raspberry Pi in regard to this 'LSB' error.

I eventually found out that the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` script that is run, will error out right away with `status=6` if a specific file does not exist, namely `/etc/sysconfig/network`.
I have no idea why this file is required, as on another system I work on the file exists but is empty. But it didn't exist out of the box with the Centos 7 OS I got for my Raspberry. After going through all other steps (remove Network Manager, set static IP in ifcfg file, kill dhc process for Network Manager, etc) if you still get this error just try:

```
touch /etc/sysconfig/network
```

The file can be empty. Just has to exist.

Then restart network service:

```
systemctl restart network
```

And voila. I realize this is a very small fix, but I went through all the headaches and tries above before finding this and I was good to go after.

Comment: WTF is going on here. How could this be right. How is this not bigger bug.

Answer (score 7):

I recently have had the same issue i.e. network.service failure

> **Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking**

The solution worked for me was disabling the NetworkManger:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

Rebooted and network.service was **active (running)**.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
BOOTPROTO=none
```

instead of

```
BOOTPROTO=static
```

The former is the correct syntax in RHEL / CentOS 7.

Comment: Could you please explain how this is might help solve the problem here, if you are posing it as an answer ? Otherwise, you can add it as a comment, saying it is something to try.

Comment: Hint: the basis for this recommendation can be found in [CentOS docs](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)...

Comment: You're referencing CentOS 5 documentation?!  That's completely irrelevant to CentOS 7,

Comment: This answer is correct. Just because there is no glimmer you should not downvote correct answers. In RedHat 7 there is no `BOOTPROTO=STATIC`. Reference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167083/bootproto-none-static-dhcp-and-etc-resolv-conf

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error trying to start i2p as service. I noticed however that parts of the Linux Standard Base support package were not installed on my system. After installing those there was no problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/sysconfig/network` is a global (across all network cards) configuration file. It tells the system boot scripts whether we even want networking.

It can contain things like:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=mybox
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

The absence of this file signals the system boot scripts to not even bother going through the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*`, which is why your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file was never even used before you touched the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the `BOOTTOPRO=""` and `IPADDR=""` lines.
I came to this thread with the same problem. Initially, I had added the BOOTTOPRO and IPPADDR lines to set static values for enp0s3. After deleting these two lines, I was able to do `systemctl restart network.service`

Comment: If you remove `IPADDR=...`then you cannot configure a static IP. This is not really helpful.