# dhclient Active for Interfaces with BOOTPROTO=none

Tags: centos, networking, bridge, dhclient

I'm facing a strange issue with my Linux bridge system (CentOS 7.6.1810).  I have two interfaces configured with a bridged network (IP of the bridge is 192.168.42.253).  When I reboot the system, it looks quite OK:

```
> route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 br0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

After a while though, dhclient starts to interfere with the network configuration:

```
> route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 br0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0
```

It then pulls a second IP address from my DHCP server and assigns it to `enp1s0`.  It also changes the routing table, so that the bridge routes external traffic from the bridge itself back into the network-site of the bridge, but not the gateway-side of it.  This is quite annoying, as I have to reboot the system (or modify the routing tables by hand) to make things like "yum update" work again on the bridge.

Here are the configuration files that I have created for bridge:

```
> sudo cat ifcfg-br0
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR=192.168.42.253
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
ZONE=public

> sudo cat ifcfg-enp1s0
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="no"
PEERDNS="no"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
IPV6_PEERDNS="no"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="no"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp1s0"
UUID="510ed878-4443-4252-9b96-860d4f045b2e"
DEVICE="enp1s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BRIDGE=br0

> sudo cat ifcfg-enp0s20u3
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="no"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
IPV6_PEERDNS="no"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="no"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp0s20u3"
UUID="510ed878-4443-4252-9b96-860d4f045b2e"
DEVICE="enp0s20u3"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BRIDGE=br0
```

NetworkManager does not seem to be active:

```
> sudo nmtui
NetworkManager is not running.
```

I have looked at [BOOTPROTO=none | static | dhcp and /etc/resolv.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167083/bootproto-none-static-dhcp-and-etc-resolv-conf/), but according to it, my configuration should be ok and dhclient should not be active.

UPDATE: After a reboot of the system, I have seen that dhclient comes up for the interface.  I have to kill it manually to make sure that the routing table is not modified and the additional IP is being assigned.  According to /proc, the parent PID of the dhclient process is 1.

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong with this kind of configuration?  Thanks!